# send_mail only works in terminal in django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to get my website to send a email when a button is pressed. However, it only sends a email when I use send_mail in the shell and does nothing when the button is pressed.

I currently have the following in my settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '#'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '#'
```

The # is of course only there for this question

In my html file I have

```
 <form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit" name="place_order" class="btn btn-success">
   Place Order</button>
 </form>
```

the place_order links up with my views.py which checks whether or not the button is clicked

```
 checkout = request.POST.get('place_order')
        if checkout:
            send_mail('Django test mail', 'this is django test body', 
            '#', ['#'], fail_silently=False,)
            messages.info(request, f'Your order has been placed!')
```

Comment: Well then likely you trigger *another* view, or the view you trigger does not reaches this statement. Can you make a `print('test')` statement above the `send_make` line, and see if it indeed is executed.

Comment: Perhaps you should check with `checkout is not None`, since right now, for an empty string, `if checkout` will be false as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem print('test') doesnt work for any of my other if statements even if the code below it works perfectly

Comment: well then you are likely triggering the wrong view. You need the interpret to run over this line when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

there is no value in post request named `place_order` because its a `button`, not a `input` so if statement would be `false` and `send_mail` wont be triggered:

```
 checkout = request.POST.get('place_order')
        if checkout: # <=== here
            send_mail('Django test mail', 'this is django test body', 
            '#', ['#'], fail_silently=False,)
            messages.info(request, f'Your order has been placed!')
```

so if you change your `HTML` to something like:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="place_order" value="blablabla"/> # value shouldn't be empty
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
   Place Order</button>
 </form>
```